# kendo combobox -webkit-appearance

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to mimic the arrow in IE for select boxes for a kendo combobox, but I am unable to make that happen yet. I got rid of the kendo combobox arrow, but I can't replace it with the standard arrow for Internet Explorer ( it works in Chrome and Firefox )

```
<div>
    <input class="k-input" role="combobox"></input>
<div>
```

I've tried:

```
input::ms-check, input::ms-expand, .k-input {     
-webkit-appearance: menulist;
-moz-appearance: menulist;
-o-appearance: menulist;
appearance: menulist; }
```

Comment: IE does not support appearance CSS http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance

Comment: if thats true then how does the arrow appear on any select tag in IE? where is it implemented?